# Two Samba servers but only one is available

Tags: windows-10, samba

I have two linux systems one running Centos7 and the other Fedora30.
The SMB.CONF files of both are as close to identical as I can make them.
My Windows 10 system can only find the Centos System.  I have disabled IPV6 & selinux on both but it has not helped.

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: DropBear  - smbd version 4.9.1
SMB.CONF
[global]
   workgroup = BGS
    server string = DropBear Reborn
    hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.122.0/24
    max log size = 500
    security = user
    map to guest = Bad Password
    allow insecure wide links = yes
    follow symlinks = yes
    unix extensions = yes
    log level = 1

[Public2]
    comment = Public
    path = /media/share
    read only = no
    public  = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
    browseable = yes
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777

Comment: unBear smbd  Version 4.10.10
SMB.CONF
   workgroup = BGS
   server string = SunBear
   load printers = no
   hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.122.0/24
   max log size = 500
   security = user
   map to guest = Bad Password
   allow insecure wide links = yes
   follow symlinks = yes
   unix extensions = yes
   log level = 4

[public]
   comment = Public
   path = /media/share
   read only = no
   public = yes
   guest only = yes
   guest ok = yes
   writable = yes
   browseable = yes
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777